# Share common query result for all Hibernate Entities

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, caching, entity

I'm currently using JPA entities with a Hibernate implementation an was wondering if there is a way to share a certain query result between all entities of the same class?

What I want is to implement a simple Transient method in the entity which checks if certain property of the current entity is in a list of values that's stored in another table in the DB, but I don't want each entity executing this extra query to get the list of values.

Is there any way to store this cached query result and access it within the specific entity?

For example:

Person entity:

```
private Long id;
private String name;

...

@Transient
public boolean isIdBanned(){
(check against the cached list)
}
```

Here I would want to check if the Person's id is inside a banned ids list using the cached query result.

Comment: Is it safe to assume that this cached list is something that your application holds in a static registry global to the application or is it something which perhaps a web interceptor loads once and you reuse the cached list for that particular request?

Comment: @Naros right now the List is stored in a configuration database table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is where I would typically advocate having a separation of *domain* and *persistence* objects.

From the view point of persistence, your `Person` entity does not care about this ban list.  It serves absolutely no concrete purpose from a persistence perspective and thus I'd argue it doesn't belong anywhere in the `Person` entity.

From your domain's perspective, you're basically trying to satisfy the requirement of providing a way for your domain to ask the `Person`, *"Hey are you banned?"*

```
@Service
public class PersonBanService {
  @Cacheable
  @Transactional(readOnly = true)
  public List<Integer> getBanList() {
    return personBanRepository.findAll();
  }
}

@Service
public class PersonDomainService {
  @Transactional(readOnly = true)
  public List<Person> getPersons() {
    List<Integer> banList = personBanService.getBanList();
    List<PersonEntity> people = personRepository.findAll();
    return people.stream()
      .map( p -> new Person( p, banList.contains( p.getId() ) ) )
      .collect( Collectors.toList() );
  }
}
```

Basically, the `PersonDomainService` acts as a mediator of these two concerns.  It fetches the ban list for you once per domain method call and then passes that along with the `PersonEntity` instance to a domain wrapper class, `Person` that internally uses that list.

The nice part here is that the `PersonBanService` may elect to cache the returned results, allowing perhaps that list to be shared across a cluster or multiple request invocations without hitting the database using whatever cache framework you have available.

Now inside your `Person` domain object

```
public Person(PersonEntity entity, boolean banned) { 
  this.person = entity;
  this.banned = banned;
}

public boolean isBanned() {
  return banned;
}
```

Comment: thanks for this! I didn't think about this approach before!